# How to move parent div when child div touches parent div boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, mousemove

I have three div's in the following code.

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here "inner" div is moving with mouseMove event. How can I move "outer" div along with "inner" div when "inner" div touches the top and left of "outer" div but "outer" div should not move when "inner" div inside or don't touch "outer" div?

```js
var innerDiv = $('#inner');
var outerDiv = $('#outer');
var outDim = outerDiv.offset();
outDim.right = (outDim.left + outerDiv.width());
outDim.bottom = (outDim.top + outerDiv.height());
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = (e.clientX) - 15;
  var y = (e.clientY) - 15;
  var x_allowed = x >= outDim.left && x <= (outDim.right - innerDiv.width());
  var y_allowed = y >= outDim.top && y <= (outDim.bottom - innerDiv.height());
  if (y_allowed) {
    innerDiv.css({
      top: y + 'px',
    });
  } else {
    //fine tune tweaks
    if (y >= outDim.top) {
      innerDiv.css({
        top: (outDim.bottom - innerDiv.height()) + 'px',
      });
    }
    if (y <= (outDim.bottom - innerDiv.height())) {
      innerDiv.css({
        top: outDim.top + 'px',
      });
    }
  }

  if (x_allowed) {
    innerDiv.css({
      left: x + 'px'
    });
  } else {
    //fine tune tweaks
    if (x >= outDim.left) {
      innerDiv.css({
        left: outDim.right - innerDiv.width() + 'px',
      });
    }
    if (x <= (outDim.right - innerDiv.width())) {
      innerDiv.css({
        left: outDim.left + 'px',
      });
    }
  }


});
```

```css
#wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#inner {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/apelluri2/baqfg8t5/3/%60)